# is it possible to bind multiple components to intentservice in android

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-intentservice, android-service-binding

As of I know, we can use Bound service if we wanna bind multiple clients to a service. But, there are many advantages of intent service over a service. So, I am wondering if it is possible to bind multiple components to an intent service. Also, is it possible to let the intent service handle the requests from different processes as well(may be via IPC(AIDL) or some other technique). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can bind different clients to your IntentService, just be sure that you've implemented [OnBind](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29) method in your Service class. After that you can use IPC in order to pass data in and from your Service in a way which you think is more comfortable for you. More details in the [Developers page](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#IPC)